# Regular expressions .Net Regex.Replace

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to replace a named match by some constant value or another named match?
Lets say I have input string and if it contains "123" replace "123" by "567"
if the string has "234" I want it replace by "678". I need to do that using Regex.Replace as I use API which uses Regex.Replace and changing that API is not what I want.

So what I provide for that API matchPattern & replacePattern to get something like that:

`Regex.Replace("123", matchPattern, replacePattern)` returns "567"

`Regex.Replace("234", matchPattern, replacePattern)` returns "678"

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to pass in a single, fixed `replacePattern` that does different things depending on the input?

Comment: Why not just execute two Regex.Replace commmands?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with just a regex replace call. But you can provide a callback function:

```
public String Replacer(Match m) {
    if (m.Groups[0].Value == "123")
       return "567";
    else if (m.Groups[0].Value == "456")
       return "678";
}

resultString = Regex.Replace(subject, @"\b(?:123|456)\b", new MatchEvaluator(Replacer));
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect there would some others ways to do this, but i came up with the following approach that uses `named groups` and `anonymous methods`.

I have assumed in my example that 123, 456, 789 will be replaced with 111, 444, 777 respectively while 000 will remain intact in the string.

I have used an approach to `name the group` a value that will be a use as `a replacement value`. For example here in this part:

(?<111>123) = value 123 will be replace by 111 where 111 is also the name of the group.

So, a general pattern would become: `(?<ValueToReplace>ValueToSearch)`

Here is a sample code:

```
Dim sampleText = "123 456 789 000"
Dim re As New Regex("\b(?<111>123)\b|\b(?<444>456)\b|\b(?<777>789)\b")
Dim count As Integer = re.Matches(sampleText).Count
Dim contents As String = re.Replace(sampleText, New MatchEvaluator(Function(c) re.GetGroupNames().Skip(1).ToArray().GetValue(c.Captures(0).Index Mod count).ToString()))
```

From your approach I expect you work in VB.Net but i have attached a C# version too.

Here, is the C# version:

```
var sampleText = @"123 456 789 000";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\b(?<111>123)\b|\b(?<444>456)\b|\b(?<777>789)\b");
int count = re.Matches(sampleText).Count;
string contents = re.Replace(sampleText, new MatchEvaluator((c) => re.GetGroupNames().Skip(1).ToArray().GetValue(c.Captures[0].Index % count).ToString()));
```